# Database cleanup

Tags: sql-server, database, resource-cleanup

I inherited a SQL server database that is not well formatted. ( some consulting company came in to do the project and left without completing it)
the main issues I have with this database are:

- Data types: a lot of tinyint and text types.
- Tables are not normalized: some of the keys are names instead of seq ids.
- A lot of tables that I am not sure are being used
- a lot of stored procedures that i am not sure are being used
- Badly named tables and stored procs

I also inherited the asp.net application that runs against this database.

I would like to clean this database up. I understand that changing the datatypes will have to happen at each table. for getting rid of all the extra tables and stored procs. what is the easiest way to do so.
any other tips to make it cleaner and smaller is appreciated.

I want to also mention that I have RedGate tools installed.( if that helps).

Thank you

Comment: You wrote: "Tables are not normalized: some of the keys are names instead of seq ids."

Just want to point out that normalization has nothing to do with using natural or surrogate keys. The database can very well be normalized and use names for primary- and foreign keys.

Comment: This is pretty open ended and not much detail to get a good answer, in my opinion.  You can use redgate's "Find Invalid Objects" and its "Smart Rename" feature to see where things are referenced.  But you also have references to those resources in your .NET application.  So long story short, it's going to be a slow process of fixing things.  A lot of manual checking and a bit of trial (with smart rename!) and error to find out how the cleanup will ultimately pan out.

Comment: jpw- I am aware of that names can be used for FKs, i am saying that if  table B has columns(seqid, Description), in table A the link is A.Description = B.Description.

Comment: Two options: 1. Understand what it does, build a new one in parallel and migrate the data; 2. Make incremental changes to your existing system

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Sql Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)  they allow to create a project from a live database.  Some of the things you can do in there is right click 'Find Usages' for the tables, views and functions.

So long as the previous developer used stored procedures and views rather than querying directly, it should find references to your project that way, without killing your project.

Also, for finding stored procedures that are not used, put in some basic logging at the top of each stored procedure in your application, after X amount of days, those that haven't been logged in your table are likely safe to remove, else a tedious search through your .NET code will find them.